# How do I resample data into a daily value using time specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have downloaded a few years worth of five minute OHLCV (Open High Low Close Volume) data for the NQ Futures ticker. I want to resample this data into daily OHLCV.

The problem I have is that the data comes from the CME exchange and a trading day ends at 17:00CT and a new trading day starts at 18:00CT and the times from 18:00CT to 23:59CT are included in the aggregation for the daily OHLCV. Therefore my OHLCV are incorrect after the resampling.

How can I aggregate the 5 minute OHLCV data into daily OHLCV starting from 18:00CT to 17:00CT?

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# read in the data from the csv file
nq_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Python\data\NQ Data Extract 2023-07-20.csv")

# merge the date and time columns into one column and make key column
nq_data['DateTime'] = nq_data['Date'] + ' ' + nq_data['Time']
nq_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(nq_data['DateTime'])
nq_data.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

# drop the date and time columns
nq_data.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# resample to 1 day intervals
df_daily = nq_data.resample('1D').agg({'Open': 'first',
                                       'High': 'max',
                                       'Low': 'min',
                                       'Close': 'last',
                                       'Volume': 'sum'}).copy()

# drop entries where the open, high, low and close are all nan
df_daily.dropna(how='all', subset=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], inplace=True)
```

I've checked some examples here on resampling time series but I don't find anything that related to my issue with the start/end time.

Comment: 18:00 CDT is 24:00 UTC, is that relevant? I'm not in fintech myself so I don't know if there's some convention or something.

Comment: So there's no data from 17:00 to 18:00, right?

Comment: It'd help if you provided a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), though ironically where you're stuck is on minimizing the data. Maybe you could resample to hourly and show us the data for a day or two.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want more tips. I'm not sure why someone downvoted this without leaving a comment, but there are a few things you could improve: 1) include some data (like I said); 2) mention at least one example you've looked at, like whatever you think is the most relevant one; 3) include all relevant tags (which I already fixed: [tag:pandas]).

Comment: Comments don't support fancy formatting. Please post an answer instead.

Comment: No need to apologize :)

Answer (score 0):

I included this line to add on a day if the time is greater than 17:00:00:

```
nq_data['Date'] = np.where(
    nq_data['Time'] > '17:00:00',
    nq_data['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(1),
    nq_data['Date'])
```

Comment: This is a little fragile cause it depends on the format of the CSV instead of the resulting data. Instead you could use `nq_data['DateTime'].dt.hour > 17`, and that lets you streamline the datetime parsing with `pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates={'DateTime': ['Date', 'Time']})`.

Comment: Also, you can simplify with `Series.where` like this: `nq_data['DateTime'] = nq_data['DateTime'].where(nq_data['DateTime'].dt.hour > 17, nq_data['DateTime'] + pd.DateOffset(1))` Or you could use `.loc` like this: `nq_data.loc[nq_data['DateTime'].dt.hour > 17, 'DateTime'] += pd.DateOffset(1)`